# How can I make an instant-dependant static variabe in a class method?

Tags: c++, static, member-functions

I have a function in a class the more or less works like so:

```
class Player {
private:
    Object* minions[16]
public:
    void Summon(Object* obj);
};

Player::Summon(Object* obj) {
    static int i = 0;
    if (i == 16)
        return;
    minions[i] = obj;
    i++;
}
```

The problem arise when trying to use more than one player, like so:

```
Player playerone;
Player playerthree;
playerone.Summon(new Object("o1"));
playerthree.Summon(new Object("o2"));
```

`o1` is located in `playerone.minions[0]`, as is expected, however, `o2` is located in `playerthree.minions[1]`, the `Summon()` function using the same `i` variable.  Is there a way to make the `Summon()` function use a static `i` variable for a single instance, but use separate `i` variables for each instance?  I know I could do something like make a `for` loop to the first spot in `minions[]` equal to `NULL`, or make `i` a member of `Player` directly, but I want to know if there is a better way before I do either of those.

Comment: I know the title is less than clear, any suggestions for a better one?

Comment: If you want a variable which has a unique value for each `Player` object, the simplest thing really is to add a member to `class Player`.

Comment: I think he means "instance-dependent", which in turn presumably means something like "per instance". In which case aschepler has it: this is exactly what data members are for. Except of course for the part where a proper standard library container is called for to hold the `minions` in the first place. There probably isn't a real reason to store raw pointers to objects (as opposed to storing objects directly), either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Object* minions[16];` to a `std::vector<Object*> minions;`.  That way you can just use `minions.size()` to know how many there are, or `minions.push_back(obj);` to add one without worrying about array index stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply put `i` in each `Player`? I'd rename it something like `summonned_minion_count`, but that's the actual intent of what you want to do.

Comment: yeah, I figured I'd have to do something like this.  I was hoping there'd be a cleaner way than creating a member variable that would only be used in one function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `i` a member variable of `Player`.

Or even better you could do something like this:

```
#include <vector>

class Player {
private:
    static int const MAX_MINION_COUNT = 16;
    std::vector<Object *> minions;
public:
    void Summon(Object* obj) {
        if (minions.size() < MAX_MINION_COUNT) {
            minions.push_back(obj);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Actually, I was planning on turning minions into a list/vector eventually, but I got caught up by some unrelated glitches in other areas of the program

Answer (score 0):

Making a local variable static is effectively making it global.  You should simply make `i` a data member of `class Player`.  And probably give it a more descriptive name.